# How to create a new account from https callable function and change the auth state of browser to logged in after successful invocation of the function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I am using angular for front-end and firebase for back-end. I created a form in angular to take in some fields like first name, last name, email, password, mobile no., address etc.

When I submit the form, I want to do two things --
1. Create a user account with email and password.
2. Add a document in my users collection in firestore with the fields firstname, lastname, mobile no., address etc.
I don't want to do these 2 things on client side.

So, I created a cloud function in firebase to do the above two things like so --

```
export const register = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const firestore = admin.firestore();
    const auth = admin.auth();

    return auth.createUser({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password
    }).then(user => {
        let dbData = {};

        // Assign all fields to dbData except 'email' and 'password' because I don't want to store those fields in the database
        Object.keys(data).forEach(el => { if (el != 'email' && el != 'password') dbData[el] = data[el];});

        return firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid)
        .set(dbData)
        .then(() => {
            return 'success';
        }, error => {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Unknown error.');
        });
    }, error => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Unknown error.');
    });
});
```

I invoke the cloud function in angular with angularfire2 like this --

```
const registerFunction = this.afFunctions.functions.httpsCallable('register');
registerFunction(data)
.then(() => {
    // Account created successfully
}),
error => {
    // Error occured
});
```

The account gets created successfully. But the problem is the browser (client app) is not logged in to the account just created. I want the user to be logged in when he/she registers.

So my question is how to get the user signed in on client by calling https callable function?

Answer (score 0):

You do want to do this client side. You create a form, take the users email address and password, then call `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. The browser will be running the Firebase SDK which has an `.onAuthStateChanged` listener that will switch from `null` to `currentUser` object.

It's recommended to use validate the user own the email first though by firing a validation link first.